# How to get max row in a table with 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64).

(Apologies - I'm a newbie and I know I'm running an old version)

I have the following table:

| ID | Name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finished | 2022-07-13 17:09:48.0000000 |
| 1 | Start | 2022-07-13 17:00:48.0000000 |
| 2 | Clean | 2022-07-13 15:09:48.0000000 |
| 2 | Waiting | 2022-07-13 17:34:48.0000000 |
| 2 | Clean | 2022-07-13 12:09:48.0000000 |
| 3 | Start | 2022-07-12 18:09:48.0000000 |
| 3 | Middle | 2022-07-12 14:09:48.0000000 |
| 3 | Middle | 2022-06-13 17:09:48.0000000 |

I want to return a group that will show the max time for each ID number, but also return the `Name` value of that max row.

I can do a

```
SELECT
    ID, MAX(Time)
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY
    (ID)
```

but I need to pull in the `Name` column as well. I just want one row per ID returning the max time for that ID, and the `Name` associated with that Time & ID number

Any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing has been asked and answered so many times, but finding the right search term can be challenging. Here is how you can tackle this with your sample data.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , Name varchar(20)
    , Time datetime2
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'Finished', '2022-07-13 17:09:48.0000000')
, (1, 'Start', '2022-07-13 17:00:48.0000000')
, (2, 'Clean', '2022-07-13 15:09:48.0000000')
, (2, 'Waiting', '2022-07-13 17:34:48.0000000')
, (2, 'Clean', '2022-07-13 12:09:48.0000000')
, (3, 'Start', '2022-07-12 18:09:48.0000000')
, (3, 'Middle', '2022-07-12 14:09:48.0000000')
, (3, 'Middle', '2022-06-13 17:09:48.0000000')

select ID
    , Name
    , Time
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by s.ID order by s.Time desc)
    from @Something s
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: thank you Sean. yes i tried searching but had no luck. yours worked for me thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Just another option (a nudge less performant)

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable 
 Order By row_number() over (partition by ID order by Time desc)
```

Comment: @Jdbfkfo Small tables are fine.   Larger tables Sean's approach would be notably more performant.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work

```
select * from table
where time in (select max(time) from table group by id )
```

But other's answers seem more efficient.

I have not tested this, if it's wrong then will delete the answer.

Comment: This would work if all the values for time are unique. But if there are more than 1 row where the value for time is the same for the same id this would produce duplicates. That is not very likely but something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, It is a possible scenario and did not occur to me :( .